# C# Check if only one adapter is active / Up

Tags: c#, networking, network-programming

I need to know if only one adapter is active / up and get his name.
That's my current code

```
List<string> _adapters = new List<string>();

foreach (NetworkInterface f in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
{
    if (f.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up && !f.Name.Contains("Loopback") 
        && !f.Name.Contains("isatap") 
        && !f.Name.Contains("Pseudo") 
        && !f.Name.Contains("Teredo")
        && !f.Name.Contains("6To4"))
    {
        _adapters.Add(f.Name);
    }
}

if (_adapters.Count == 1)
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

Now I have to exclude some Tunneling and Loopback adapters like Loopback, isatap, Pseudo, Teredo, 6To4. I think this solution isn't pretty sweet. Now I ask, is there a possibility to exclude these "pseudo" Adapters completely?

**EDIT:**
I found another not 100% perfect solution to deal with that problem, but i think it's better than the comparison with the name.

```
List<string> _adapters = new List<string>();
foreach (NetworkInterface f in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
{
    if (f.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up &&
        !f.NetworkInterfaceType.ToString().Contains("Tunnel") &&
        !f.NetworkInterfaceType.ToString().Contains("Loopback"))    
    {
         Console.WriteLine(f.Name);
         _adapters.Add(f.Name.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's 100% possible to distinguish between physical and virtual network interfaces. Using WMI as per [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11756820/4265041) may get you further than the `NetworkInterface` class properties, however.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will check it.

Comment: BTW your return statement is an anti-pattern, you should consider simplifying it to `return (_adapters.Count == 1);` , and even the parenthesis  are option.